# PSQL Update a jsonb property with a concatenation to its current value

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Lets assume I have a column X which is of jsonb type. X has json's of structure

```
{"y":"some value","z":"some more values"}.
```

Now what I need to achieve is that I want to append "!!!!" to the end of  all z properties. The append operation should update the existing records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
UPDATE thetable set x=jsonb_set(x, '{z}', to_jsonb(x->>'z' || '!!!!'), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `->>` operator to get the value of `z` as `text` and the `||` operator to append the other string. Convert the result to `jsonb` with `to_jsonb()` and assign it to `z` with `jsonb_set()`.

```
SELECT jsonb_set(x, '{z}', to_jsonb(x->>'z' || '!!!!'))
       FROM elbat;
```

More info: ["9.15. JSON Functions and Operators"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: but this only updates the data on SELECT. I need to update the records themselves